# How to start the Snort service with logging enabled?

Tags: centos, logs, snort

I setup snort on Centos server and add as a service. When I use `service snortd start` command, the log file is created but it is empty. If I use `snort -q -l /var/log/snort` command, the log file created and filled with logs. What should I do in order to use `service snortd start` and have the logs work?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the init script and add `-q -l /var/log/snort` to snort. Save and restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the `/etc/sysconfig/snort` file as options will be read from there. LOGDIR (-l) is set to `/var/log/snort` by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Snort Manual v2.9.11](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/129/original/snort_manual.pdf) written under `The Snort Project`

To read packets & record them to disc, we need to specify a logging directory that If not specified, by default It is created with name `log` in current directory. If log directory is not configured in snort, It exits with an error message.

So, you need to specify the logging directory in the `init` script while starting the snort itself by typing in :

```
./snort -q -dev -l /path/to/log/file
```

Now save the script and restart the service.

Also, consider giving your time to this [Script by markus1982](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/i-want-to-start-snort-as-a-service-daemon-32771/). It would be really helpful.